# Error in gbm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, distribution = distribution, w = w, : The number of rows in x does not equal the length of y

Tags: r, machine-learning, gbm

New to the site, and R, thanks in advance for your patience and help!

I'm attempting to run a Gradient Boosted Machine learning algorithm to develop some models. (utilizing the method provided at https://github.com/ledell/useR-machine-learning-tutorial/blob/master/gradient-boosting-machines.Rmd)

So far I've read my data in and downloaded the necessary components (gbm, cvAUC)

Code Below:

```
set.seed(1)
model <- gbm(formula =~ BP_Nopay3_PMT, 
         distribution = "bernoulli",
         data = train,
         n.trees = 70,
         interaction.depth = 5,
         shrinkage = 0.3,
         bag.fraction = 0.5,
         train.fraction = 1.0,
         n.cores = NULL)`
```

and getting the following results:

```
Error in gbm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, distribution = distribution, w = w,  
: The number of rows in x does not equal the length of y.
```

My research results (google: `Error in gbm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, distribution = distribution, w = w, : The number of rows in x does not equal the length of y solved`)

lead me to the conclusion that I need to edit the `x` or `y` parameter, but I am not sure how to edit it given it is a result of the model statement.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: reproducing this error without data will be difficult. Please share your data.

Comment: however do try `model <- gbm(formula = BP_Nopay3_PMT~paste0(setdiff(names(train), "BP_Nopay3_PMT"),collapse='+'), 
         distribution = "bernoulli",
         data = train,
         n.trees = 70,
         interaction.depth = 5,
         shrinkage = 0.3,
         bag.fraction = 0.5,
         train.fraction = 1.0,
         n.cores = NULL)`

Comment: @abhiieor Trying the code returned:  

    
Error in model.frame.default(formula = BP_Nopay3_PMT ~ 
    paste0(setdiff(names(train),  : 
    variable lengths differ (found for 'paste0(setdiff(names(train), 
    "BP_Nopay3_PMT"), collapse = "+")')


The data I'm using has about 1000 variables, I will look up the best way to share a few records but I'm not certain at this moment a reasonable way to supply even a few records. (please advise?)

Still learning how to format here so thanks for reading through!